# How to get a range of cells in excel vba taking data from other sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get data for a graph in a sheet of an excel workbook using VBA. Range of data I need is in the same workbook but in a different sheet.

I need to write that range in cells format, because the column is not always the same, it changes in every execution, I mean:

```
Range(Cells(3,5),Cells(3,column).value
```

The problem appears when I take data from other sheet.

If I write:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3,5),Cells(3,column).Value
```

I have no problem, everything's ok. But when I take data from other sheet:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Sheets("Data").Range(Cells(3,5),Cells(3,column).Value
```

I get a

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

This only happens when I use the Cells format to specify a range. If I use the format `Range("E5:J5").Value` I have no problem with the sheet of the data but in this format I can't or don't know how to specify the column in each execution.

Comment: What's the value of `column` when you get the error?

Comment: Is an integer that changes inside a For Next loop. But If I always put an specific integer without changes outside loop, does not work anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because `Cells` is not properly qualified. Meaning, in this bit of code,

```
Sheets("Data").Range(Cells(3,5),Cells(3,column)).Value
```

what you are implicitly saying is

```
Sheets("Data").Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(3,5),ActiveSheet.Cells(3,column)).Value
```

which clearly makes no sense, because `ActiveSheet` is a different sheet than `Sheets("Data")`.

You can do this instead:

```
Sheets("Data").Range("E3").Resize(1, rangeWidth).Value
```

In your specific case, you can replace `rangeWidth` with `column - 4` since column `E` is column 5.